# Make a specific button in PyGObject as small as possible

Tags: python-3.x, button, gtk, toolbar, pygobject

I would like to have a toolbar button with a label but without an icon that is as small as possible. There is no need for margins between the text on the button and the border of the button. It has not to be a real toolbar. It can also be a simple horizontal line of buttons.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

        # try it as a toolbar
        toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
        for i in range(3):
            widget = Gtk.Label(str(i), expand=False)
            #widget.set_margin_start(0)
            btn = Gtk.ToolButton.new()
            btn.set_label_widget(widget)
            toolbar.insert(btn, -1)

        # try it as simple button line
        hbox = Gtk.HBox()
        for i in range(5):
            btn = Gtk.Button(label=str(i), expand=False, relief=2)
            hbox.pack_start(btn, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)

        # layout
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(toolbar, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
        vbox.pack_start(hbox, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
        self.add(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

**EDIT**: Not all buttons in the application should be like this. I need this specific "style" only for some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding some CSS properties should do the trick. Here's a quick modification of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

# Added code starts here
from gi.repository import Gdk

css = b"""
.small-button {
  min-height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
"""

css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_data(css)

Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
    css_provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
)
# End of added code

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

        # try it as a toolbar
        toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
        for i in range(3):
            widget = Gtk.Label(str(i), expand=False)
            #widget.set_margin_start(0)
            btn = Gtk.ToolButton.new()
            btn.set_label_widget(widget)
            toolbar.insert(btn, -1)

        # try it as simple button line
        hbox = Gtk.HBox()
        for i in range(5):
            btn = Gtk.Button(label=str(i), expand=False, relief=2)
            style_ctx = btn.get_style_context()
            style_ctx.add_class('small-button')
            hbox.pack_start(btn, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)

        # layout
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(toolbar, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
        vbox.pack_start(hbox, expand=False, fill=False, padding=0)
        self.add(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Changing the CSS of just a specific set of widgets can be done by appointing a new class to them. First get the `GtkStyleContext` of those widgets and then use its `add_class('class-name')` method:

```
style_ctx = button.get_style_context()
style_ctx.add_class('small-button')
```

See the [theming section](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html) in the GTK documentation for more information about CSS theming.

Run your GUI with the [GtkInspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector) to inspect the widget's CSS properties.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about CSS. Where is the `Gtk.Button` in your example? Please provide working code.

Comment: It is working code, edited now to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated my subject and question. It is still mystic for me. I don'T see a connection between the  `Gtk.Button` and the "style". Also can not find a description about that in the GTK-CSS-doc - but I asume there is one.

Comment: I would asume something like `Gtk.Button.set_style()` (is deprecated).

Comment: e.g. I don't understand the docu of https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.add_class

Comment: Tried to explain some more. Only the bottom row of buttons is now shrunken.

Comment: Sidequestion: Setting the `small-button` class to the style-context of the ToolbarButtons has no effect. Can I modify the style of a ToolbarButton, too?

Comment: Apparently adding the `small-button` class directly to the `GtkToolButton` has no effect, but it has a `GtkButton` as child which does work. So you can do `style_ctx = btn.get_child().get_style_context()` for the `GtkToolButton`s. Found this by using the GtkInspector.